# In Docker Compose can I have services exiting

Tags: docker-compose

I am trying to use Docker Compose to build a series of services that make up a web server and its components and then make them live.  However, some of the "services" I want there are just to create "Volumes" to populate directories such as node_modules, or bower_components.  This allows me to have much more control over the versioning of things.

What I can't find out is what happens to these services if they exit (with exit(0)).  Does the remainder of the services keep running successfully.

I "could" perhaps have a small task which just waits for the sigint like so:-

```
(function() {
  'use strict';
  process.on('SIGINT', function() {
    process.exit(0);    
  });
})();
```

but this seems like a bit of a fudge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your service is up just do certain job and die why instead of letting them to hang till you manually kill them, just not monitor them via `docker-compose logs -f ${service}` / using stdout/stderr of their specific containers?
 Docker-compose streams logs into specific container-bound log file, and you can access to its data both via docker-compose cli, docker API, readable file stream and what else. While majority of theese could be overkill for your case - using `docker-compose logs -f` is very convinient method to get container-specific activity report.

Still if you really want to keep them alive you can create npm script 
(via `package.json`) that will attach signal event handler as you wrote from specific file. You can add such command to the service `command`

```
     command: sh -c 'do your stuff; npm run wait-signal-server'
```

You can use plain js file and just use it via `node file.js` but using/ running as npm scripts is more convenient way for such things - in my oppinion